# Function not called in the appended rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have table for which I am generating rows dynamically. For getting 'select' list I am calling a function within the 'select' tags.

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 5px;" class="form_style_table" id="add_resource_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="requested_on" value="<?php echo $requested_on; ?>" class="date"/> :Requested On</td>
        <td colspan="5" align="right" class="border_bottom_1">
            <span class="float_left" id="status_msg"></span>
            <input type="button" value="Add Resource" id="add_resource_button" class="orange"/> 
        </td>
    </tr>               
    <th align="middle" valign="middle">Resource Allocated</th>
    <th align="middle" valign="middle">Role</th>
    <th align="middle" valign="middle">Tentatively Starts On</th>
    <tr>
        <td>    
            <select name="add_resource">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <?php echo select_data_as_options("project_resources", "name", $resource_allocated); ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="add_role">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <?php echo select_data_as_options("project_roles", "name", $role); ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="start_date_tentative" class="date_one" value="<?php echo $tentatively_starts_on; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The function for 'select' tag is as follows:

```
function select_data_as_options($table_name, $field_name, $selected){
$select=mysql_query("SELECT id, $field_name FROM $table_name");
$options = '';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
    $selected_attr = '';
    extract($row);
    if(strtolower($selected) == strtolower($row[$field_name]) or $selected == $id)
        $selected_attr = "selected='selected'";
    $options.="<option value='$id' $selected_attr>" . ucfirst($row[$field_name]) ."</option>";
}
return $options;}
```

I am appending the rows using the below code:

```
$("#add_resource_button").click(function () {
    var $row = $('<tr><td><select name="add_resource" class="resource"><option value="">-- Select --</option><?php echo select_data_as_options("project_resources", "name", $resource_allocated); ?></select></td><td><select name="add_role" class="role"><option value="">-- Select --</option><?php echo select_data_as_options("project_roles", "name", $role); ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="start_date_tentative" class="date_one" value="<?php echo $tentatively_starts_on; ?>"/></td></tr>').appendTo('#add_resource_table');
    $row.find('.date_one').datepicker();
```

Here the the rows after the append is not calling the function and so the select options are not displayed.
Similarly the variables used in the append are displayed as it is.

Please suggest a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you generate dynamically? in `client side or server side`?

Comment: `$("#add_resource_button").on('click', function(){...` might help

Comment: @Murali Client side....